# How do I sort a Mongo collection by geocoordinates near

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, geojson

I have the following Mongo call, how do I return a *sorted* list of places depending on the nearest geo coordinates?

```
Venues.find({'location.coordinates': 
            { $near :
      { $geometry :
        { type : "Point" ,
          coordinates: params.coordinates } 
        },
        $maxDistance : 10000
            } 
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use $near, MongoDB returns the results [sorted with nearest distance first by default](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/).
If this is what you don't want, use $geoWithin instead.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong because I get 0 results. Perhaps what I need is $geoWithin.